# How to use env variables in angular scss to set up different styles depending on environments

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

First of all, i searched all day for similar topics but none could resolve my case, or if such a topic exists with a solution, i am sorry for not finding it and asking again.

So i am currently working on an angular 14 project for my client, and i need different styles according to the environment we build the app.

Mainly, it is to change the theme color if in dev env, test env or prod env.

For now, the solution has been to build a specific scss file for each environment, but i feel like this is a poor design solution and something more elegant exists out there.

here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "anonymous_project",
  "version": "5.10.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start:docker": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy-docker.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "package:build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:aot": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:css": "sass --style=compressed src/assets/sass/environment-styles/prod-main.scss:src/assets/sass/environment-styles/prod-main.css",
    "build:css-dev": "sass --style=compressed src/assets/sass/environment-styles/dev-main.scss:src/assets/sass/environment-styles/dev-main.css",
    "build:css-int": "sass --style=compressed src/assets/sass/environment-styles/int-main.scss:src/assets/sass/environment-styles/int-main.css",
    "build:css-edu": "sass --style=compressed src/assets/sass/environment-styles/edu-main.scss:src/assets/sass/environment-styles/edu-main.css",
    "build:css-aq": "sass --style=compressed src/assets/sass/environment-styles/aq-main.scss:src/assets/sass/environment-styles/aq-main.css"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@stomp/rx-stomp": "^0.3.5",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.4.4",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.13",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^2.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.23.2",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.26",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "light-server": "^2.9.1",
    "lodash.camelcase": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash.zip": "^4.2.0",
    "map.prototype.tojson": "^0.1.3",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-icons-css": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.5.3",
    "ngx-window-token": "5.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.2",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^14.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "reselect": "^4.1.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "simplebar": "4.2.3",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.4.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.43.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.11",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

and for example the environment.prod.scss file (but one env css file exists for each env):

```scss
@import "assets/sass/environment-styles/prod-main.css";
@import "common.css"; // contains the shared scss that's not dependent on the environment used
```

the ideal solution in my point of view would be to retrieve the .env informations in a scss file and put scss variables according to the env used instead of having to build a different css for each and every environments used.

Thank you

Comment: SCSS can't retrieve env files, and the rest of your codebase can do so only at build time, not at run time.  The approach you're currently using -- keeping the environment-specific CSS in environment-specific CSS files, and linking to the appropriate one on build -- is exactly what I'd use for this.